# Formatting loop for strings

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

I'm having trouble formatting the strings below. Trying to keep the message centered with the borders, but having a hard time executing it. Below is what output I want and below that is my code I have so far. Note: I need to have a space on the left and right columns of the longest line and I need to utilize the split() func.

```
+---------------+
|     STOP!     |
| DANGER AHEAD  |
| Drive Safely! |
+---------------+

def border_sign(note):
    letter_count = 0
    for i in note:
        letter_count += 1
        return "+-------+\n| {} |\n+-------+\n".format(note)
 border_sign("STOP\nDANGER AHEAD\nDrive safely!")
```

Comment: Is this how the code is set up exactly in your editor? Because you are returning inside your loop.

Comment: And it's iterating over the characters, too.

Comment: And you're formatting the entire `note`, and using a counter that doesn't do anything, and not doing anything with `i`...

Comment: Why are you using a loop? In your example, you never make use of it.

Comment: I assumed I needed to count the largest string and then add a space for the column, but realized it was wrong.

Comment: I will be using other test functions as well, not just this string.

Answer (score 2):

Split the string into separate lines, then center each line. Remember to either print each line immediately within the function, build up a list, or yield each line rather than returning after the first line. You can also determine and use a calculated width rather than a static value.

```
def border_sign(note):
    note = note.splitlines()
    m = len(max(note, key=len))
    yield ('-'*m).join('++')
    for line in note:
        yield ("|{:^%d}|" % m).format(line)
    yield ('-'*m).join('++')

print(*border_sign("STOP\nDANGER AHEAD\nDrive safely!"), sep='\n')
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the split. If I was using other test functions, how would I go about yielding the correct amount of '+'s and '-'s?

Comment: @AlanWakke - See the edit. The `+`s don't change (it's simply one in each corner), but you can calculate the necessary space and `-` characters based on the maximum width.

Answer (score 1):

Quick sample to consider, not production ready code:

```
def border_sign(note):
    rows = note.splitlines()
    mlen = len(max(rows, key=len))
    print "+" + "-" * (2+mlen) + "+"
    for row in rows:
        print ("| {:^"+str(mlen)+"} |").format(row)
    print "+" + "-" * (2+mlen) + "+"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def border_sign(x):
    splitted = x.splitlines()
    M = max(map(len,splitted))
    horiz = '+-%s-+' % (M*'-')
    patiz = '| {0: ^%d} |' %  M
    print(horiz,*map(patiz.format,splitted), horiz, sep='\n')

border_sign("STOP\nDANGER AHEAD\nDrive safely!")
```

`patiz.format` is a function, then can be used in `map`